# Weird Water Look?

Tags: baking

I was trying to create a water animation and noticed this was the baked look? I hadn't experienced this before and couldn't figure out how to fix it, I did restart blender and delete all the water stuff and tried again, but came up with the same result. If this is a copy of another question please direct me to the orginal.

[image]

Comment: From the img looks like the viewport shading is set to solid. Change it to texture or material.

Comment: Also the water is floating on the obstacle by what looks like high amounts. The fluid world I changed the size of twice. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Possibly not related, but I notice from your screenshot that the fluid domain has been scaled. You should Apply Scale.